# Center div vertically using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap 4, i want to center the div with id of `table` vertically in the center of the view screen , i try to use ```align-items-center on it's parent element but that does not work.

here is my HTML :

```
<div id="gameTable" class="d-flex h-100">
        <div class="container align-items-center text-center h-100">
            <table class="table text-center" id="table">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="align-middle">1</td>
                  <td class="align-middle">2</td>
                  <td class="align-middle">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="align-middle">4</td>
                  <td class="align-middle">5</td>
                  <td class="align-middle">6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="align-middle">7</td>
                  <td class="align-middle">8</td>
                  <td class="align-middle">9</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" id="quit">Quit Game</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and here is my css :

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#table {
    height: 70%;
}

#gameTable {
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong with my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`align-items-center` should be used with the flexbox container (`d-flex`). You can also somplify your code like below:

```css
#table {
 height:70%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="gameTable" class="d-flex align-items-center vh-100">
  <div class="container  text-center"  id="table">
    <table class="table text-center h-100">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="align-middle">1</td>
          <td class="align-middle">2</td>
          <td class="align-middle">3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="align-middle">4</td>
          <td class="align-middle">5</td>
          <td class="align-middle">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="align-middle">7</td>
          <td class="align-middle">8</td>
          <td class="align-middle">9</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="quit">Quit Game</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but it minimize the height of the table rows, i want to keep the height of table rows as it is

Comment: I also do not want to use flex, so if there is any other way please tell me